# How do I get the data from one list referenced in a second list

Tags: 2010

I have 2 list one is a unique with project numbers the second is a combination of financial data for each project.  this is a classic 1 to many relationship and all i want is a summarization of cost from the 2nd (many) list.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact report you are trying to build, however, one option is as follows:

Create a page with a wep part showing each list, then use the web part connection functionality to link the project list to the data list. From there, you can select a specific project and it will narrow the second list down to only items from that project. If you want a sum from a column of numbers, you can change the view of the second webpart to include a totals sum value.